# Error Active Directory Authentication Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to authenticate with AD and always give me the following error
"comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839" and I do not know what else to try.

The User's Dn is the following:
CN = cfigari, OU = Development, OU = Systems, DC = fyfdevelopers, DC = cl

```
<authentication-manager>
            <ldap-authentication-provider  
                    user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=Users"
                    user-search-filter="(uid={0})" 
                    user-search-base="ou=Users"
                    group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
                    group-search-base="ou=groups"
                    group-role-attribute="cn"
                    role-prefix="ROLE_">
            </ldap-authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

<ldap-server url="ldap://127.0.0.1:389/dc=fyfdevelopers,dc=cl" manager-dn="cn=Administrador" manager-password="XXXX"/>
```